# c++ Is there a way to effectively comunicate with thread without interrupting his job

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous, boost-thread

I have the following scenario:

I can create an object with some arguments and it will load asynchronously (using `boost::thread`) one directory, which will have many subdirectories and there are many many files, and save to specific directory on disk. The files can be loaded from web or anything else and it can take some minutes to finish the job.

Just after creating the object user may want to load one specific file. Right now I am checking if the file exists (meaning the thread has alread downloaded it), otherwise I can call `thread.join()` to ensure all files are loaded or check the file existence every 100 ms or sth like that. But is there a way to do it better, meaning the thread that is doing his job will inform me when the wanted file is loaded, using some callback or sth like that?

Comment: What is "the object"? Why don't your downloader thread create another thread (actually, use a thread pool for better performance) to load a just downloaded file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use boost::condition variable  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html

1. Add 2 variables, one boolean flag and one string with filePath.
2. When thread which is opening the file finds that there is file which it is looking for, set flag on true, and filePath. Wait for the flag to be changed on condition variable
3. Thread which is loading files in background everytime it loads file it checks the flag and filePath, if the flag is set on true and the file it loaded is as expected notify the thread.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you can use a callback, for example you could have a set of observed files in the thread, and for every file downloaded you search in the set, and if the file you just donwloaded is there, you fire the callback, possibly in another thread so the thread will continue its job. Try to use a set to the find wil be faster, for example faster then searching in a vector.

Comment: The thing is I don't know what are the names of files until I open given files in the directory (this is not typical file system)

Comment: If you don't know the name of the file, how can you check if it already downloaded or not? You only can wait for all the files and then search downloaded files.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a concurrent container (native implementation in MS VC++, linux alternative: Intel TBB) and just add downloaded files to it :) then you can issue a .find or anything else.

This way you don't have to worry about locks and other threat safety stuff.